# Определить клик по элементу, не по потомку.

Tags: jquery

Метод .click() срабатывает если нажать на потомок элемента. 
Как сделать, чтобы срабатывал клик ТОЛЬКО по элементу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

дополню ответ [[@markuper](/users/5928/markuper)](/users/5928/markuper)

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>
    </div>
</div>
```

далее

```
$('.outer')
    .click(function(){         // вешаем основной обработчик на родителя
        alert('outer');        
    })
    .children()
    .click(function(e){        // вешаем на потомков
        e.stopPropagation();   // предотвращаем всплытие
    });
```

[пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/9Wsgt/)

- [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 2):

e.stopPropagation - для отмены распространения не на потомки, а на родителей, если на родителях где то висит обработчик клик он сработает, если не отменить. Что бы кликнуть только по элементу нужно проверить таргет на который кликнули. $(e.target).is('a') - например.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая ситуация, помогло css свойство: **pointer-events: none;**
Это не панацея, но иногда может пригодиться.